# Could not find function "(<-"

Tags: r

I am getting the following error.

`Error in (firstdata$gender == "male") <- 1 :`

`could not find function "(<-"`

Here is my code

`firstdata$gender_num <- (firstdata$gender=="male") <- 1`

`firstdata$gender_num <- (firstdata$gender=="female") <- 0`

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Can you provide enough context to make this a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help others replicate the error?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to assign values to a subset of your data. What you have posted is not correct `R` syntax. It should be `firstdata[firstdata$gender == "male"] <- 1`. `firstdata$gender == "male"` creates a logical vector to subset the rows of `firstdata` for assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ifelse` in this context (if `gender` is dichotomous in your data):

```
firstdata$gender_num <- ifelse(firstdata$gender == "male", 1, 0)
```

Or

```
firstdata$gender_num <- as.numeric(firstdata$gender == "male")
```